# MS Graph keeps saying "Insufficient privileges" even with correct permissions

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make a POST request to the graph API of MS using PHP. In my registerd app in azure I added the permission `Calendars.ReadWrite` with type `application`.

However as soon as I hit the endpoint:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xx@xx.xx/calandars`

I get a 403 with the message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

I cannot figure out why this happens...
I also added (and removed) the `Calandar.ReadBasic.All` but that does not change a thing.

What am I doing wrong here, as docs cleary state when hitting the endpoint for other users the token must be on application type.

Comment: Something to do with this perhaps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-11: _"Important: Administrators can configure application access policy to limit app access to specific mailboxes and not to all the mailboxes in the organization, even if the app has been granted the application permissions of Calendars.Read or Calendars.ReadWrite."_

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Is the endpoint URL correct?

Shouldn't it be `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xx@xx.xx/calendars` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/xx@xx.xx/calandars`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).